# matplotlib: How to plot a closed ring in a radar plot using fill_between? (My attempt leaves a gap.)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm attempting to use fill_between in a radar plot to paint a "ring", following the matplotlib radar example here:
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/specialty_plots/radar_chart.html

I left the radar_factory function untouched, except for an additional, overloaded function "fill_between", following the example of "fill" which is already present in the example:

```
def fill_between(self, *args, closed=True, **kwargs):
    """Override fill_between so that lines are closed by default"""
    return super().fill_between(closed=closed, *args, **kwargs)
```

As far as I understand, this should pass closed=True to a PolyCollection object. It doesn't however.

Here's the code to reproduce the problem. It's a bit longer than minimal, but I think it's important to stay close to the example from the matplotlib documentation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, RegularPolygon
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.projections.polar import PolarAxes
from matplotlib.projections import register_projection
from matplotlib.spines import Spine
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D

def radar_factory(num_vars, frame='circle'):
    # calculate evenly-spaced axis angles
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, num_vars, endpoint=False)

    class RadarAxes(PolarAxes):
        name = 'radar'
        # use 1 line segment to connect specified points
        RESOLUTION = 1

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            # rotate plot such that the first axis is at the top
            self.set_theta_zero_location('N')

        def fill(self, *args, closed=True, **kwargs):
            """Override fill so that line is closed by default"""
            return super().fill(closed=closed, *args, **kwargs)

        def fill_between(self, *args, closed=True, **kwargs):
            """
            Override fill_between so that lines are closed by default
            - CUSTOM ADDITION TO EXAMPLE - 
            """
            return super().fill_between(closed=closed, *args, **kwargs)

        def plot(self, *args, **kwargs):
            """Override plot so that line is closed by default"""
            lines = super().plot(*args, **kwargs)
            for line in lines:
                self._close_line(line)

        def _close_line(self, line):
            x, y = line.get_data()
            # FIXME: markers at x[0], y[0] get doubled-up
            if x[0] != x[-1]:
                x = np.concatenate((x, [x[0]]))
                y = np.concatenate((y, [y[0]]))
                line.set_data(x, y)

        def set_varlabels(self, labels):
            self.set_thetagrids(np.degrees(theta), labels)

        def _gen_axes_patch(self):
            # The Axes patch must be centered at (0.5, 0.5) and of radius 0.5
            # in axes coordinates.
            if frame == 'circle':
                return Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.5)
            elif frame == 'polygon':
                return RegularPolygon((0.5, 0.5), num_vars,
                                      radius=.5, edgecolor="k")
            else:
                raise ValueError("unknown value for 'frame': %s" % frame)

        def _gen_axes_spines(self):
            if frame == 'circle':
                return super()._gen_axes_spines()
            elif frame == 'polygon':
                # spine_type must be 'left'/'right'/'top'/'bottom'/'circle'.
                spine = Spine(axes=self,
                              spine_type='circle',
                              path=Path.unit_regular_polygon(num_vars))
                # unit_regular_polygon gives a polygon of radius 1 centered at
                # (0, 0) but we want a polygon of radius 0.5 centered at (0.5,
                # 0.5) in axes coordinates.
                spine.set_transform(Affine2D().scale(.5).translate(.5, .5)
                                    + self.transAxes)
                return {'polar': spine}
            else:
                raise ValueError("unknown value for 'frame': %s" % frame)

    register_projection(RadarAxes)
    return theta

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = 5
    theta = radar_factory(N, frame='polygon')

    data1 = [2,1.5,3,3,2]
    data2 = [1,0.5,2,2,1]
    spoke_labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 9), nrows=1, ncols=1,
                             subplot_kw=dict(projection='radar'))

    ax.plot(theta, data1, color='blue')
    ax.plot(theta, data2, color='blue')
    ax.fill_between(theta, y1=data1, y2=data2, color='red')
    ax.fill(theta, data1, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.25)
    ax.set_varlabels(spoke_labels)

    plt.show()
```

And its output. I would expect the red area to follow the example of the blue area and fill the whole polygon.

How do I close the red gap?

[image: Output of above code]

Comment: This does not work as [fill()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill.html) creates a polygon patch, whereas [fill_between()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html) creates a polygon PolyCollection. Two strategies come to mind: 1) intercepting args/kwargs to close the arrays as they did for lines retrospectively or 2) retrieving the polygons created by fill_between() and reconstructing the missing polygon from the vertices. The first version seems easier, especially if you restrict your inputs x, y1, y2 to either args or kwargs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution as suggested in my comment that relies on you providing `x`, `y1`, and `y2` as `args`, not `kwargs`:

```
....
def fill_between(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Override fill_between 
    - CUSTOM ADDITION TO EXAMPLE - 
    """
    if len(args) and args[0][0] != args[0][-1]:
        args = list(args)
        for i, arg in enumerate(args):
            args[i] = np.append(arg, arg[0])            
                              
    return super().fill_between(*args, **kwargs)
....

....
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = 5
    theta = radar_factory(N, frame='polygon')

    data1 = [2,1.5,3,3,2]
    data2 = [1,0.5,2,2,1]
    spoke_labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 9), nrows=1, ncols=1,
                             subplot_kw=dict(projection='radar'))

    ax.plot(theta, data1, color='blue')
    ax.plot(theta, data2, color='blue')
    ax.fill_between(theta, data1, data2, color='red')
    ax.fill(theta, data2, facecolor='blue', alpha=0.25)
    ax.set_varlabels(spoke_labels)

    plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

You can easily implement also `kwargs` parsing for greater flexibility if needed but obviously, you lose some flexibility of matplotlib parsing. However, it still parses `where` if provided as arg of len N or kwarg of len N+1:

```
#where array provided as arg of len N
ax.fill_between(theta, data1, data2, [True, True, False, True, True], color='red')    
#or as kwarg of len N+1
#ax.fill_between(theta, data1, data2, where=[True, True, False, True, True, True], color='red')
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and solution. Works like a charm and solves my problem.